# Parse HTML Table with Python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to use BeautifulSoup to parse an html table which I uploaded to http://pastie.org/8070879 in order to get the three columns (0 to 735, 0.50 to 1.0 and 0.5 to 0.0) as lists. To explain why, I will want the integers 0-735 to be keys and the decimal numbers to be values.

From reading many of the other posts on SO, I have come up with the following which does not come close to creating the lists I want. All it does is display the text in the table as is seen here http://i1285.photobucket.com/albums/a592/TheNexulo/output_zps20c5afb8.png

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("fide.html"))
table = soup.find('table')

rows = table.findAll('tr')

for tr in rows:
  cols = tr.findAll('td')
  for td in cols:
     text = ''.join(td.find(text=True))
     print text + "|",
  print
```

I'm new to Python and BeautifulSoup, so please be gentle with me! Thanks

Comment: Upload a picture of how you want the data to be presented in the end. +1 for a chess related problem.

Comment: It displays the text in a table because that's what your code does. Why don't you push each field into a dictionary where the key is your integer and the list of decimals are the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML parsers like BeautifulSoup presume that what you want is an object model that mirrors the input HTML structure. But sometimes (like in this case) that model gets in the way more than helps. Pyparsing includes some HTML parsing features that are more robust than just using raw regexes, but otherwise work in similar fashion, letting you define snippets of HTML of interest, and just ignoring the rest.  Here is a parser that reads through your posted HTML source:

```
from pyparsing import makeHTMLTags,withAttribute,Suppress,Regex,Group

""" looking for this recurring pattern:
          <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC">00-03</td>
          <td valign="top">.50</td>
          <td valign="top">.50</td>

    and want a dict with keys 0, 1, 2, and 3 all with values (.50,.50)
"""

td,tdend = makeHTMLTags("td")
keytd = td.copy().setParseAction(withAttribute(bgcolor="#FFFFCC"))
td,tdend,keytd = map(Suppress,(td,tdend,keytd))

realnum = Regex(r'1?\.\d+').setParseAction(lambda t:float(t[0]))
integer = Regex(r'\d{1,3}').setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
DASH = Suppress('-')

# build up an expression matching the HTML bits above
entryExpr = (keytd + integer("start") + DASH + integer("end") + tdend + 
                    Group(2*(td + realnum + tdend))("vals"))
```

This parser not only picks out the matching  triples, it also extracts the start-end integers and the pairs of real numbers (and also already converts from string to integers or floats at parse time).

Looking at the table, I'm guessing you actually want a lookup that will take a key like 700, and return the pair of values (0.99, 0.01), since 700 falls in the range of 620-735. This bit of code searches the source HTML text, iterates over the matched entries and inserts key-value pairs into the dict lookup:

```
# search the input HTML for matches to the entryExpr expression, and build up lookup dict
lookup = {}
for entry in entryExpr.searchString(sourcehtml):
    for i in range(entry.start, entry.end+1):
        lookup[i] = tuple(entry.vals)
```

And now to try out some lookups:

```
# print out some test values
for test in (0,20,100,700):
    print (test, lookup[test])
```

prints:

```
0 (0.5, 0.5)
20 (0.53, 0.47)
100 (0.64, 0.36)
700 (0.99, 0.01)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'm just going through it to make sure I understand and then I will mark it as my accepted answer

Comment: When I run the code, I get a KeyError:0 on the line where I try to print some test values which suggests that the key I'm looking for is not in the dictionary?

Comment: If you are getting errors, then start working backwards. Look to see what the contents of lookup are. If lookup is empty, then perhaps entryExpr didn't match anything. If entryExpr didn't match anything, then maybe the text you are parsing didn't match the example that you posted.

Comment: Lookup is empty. For sourcehtml, I entered "fide.html" which is the file in the same directory as my module and what I posted to the pastie.

Comment: "fide.html" is just a filename. You have to pass the actual file contents to scanString, not the file name.  Try entering for sourceHtml: `open("fide.html").read()`

Comment: is there another import that I'm missing?

Comment: You need to get the content to be parsed as a string. Solve that problem first. If it is in a local file named "fide.html", then you don't need to import anything special, just do `sourcehtml = open("fide.html").read()`, and then run the code above as posted. If it is elsewhere (like at a URL), then you will need to use a different imported module, such as urllib2. Or just insert the string assignment directly in your code: `sourcehtml = '''put the html text right here...'''`. This will at least show your parser is working. Then work on how to get the data as a string to input to the parser.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32226/discussion-between-thenexulo-and-paul-mcguire)

Answer (score 3):

I think the above answer is better than what I would offer, but I have a BeautifulSoup answer that can get you started. This is a bit hackish, but I figured I would offer it nevertheless.

With BeautifulSoup, you can find all the tags with certain attributes in the following way (assuming you have a soup.object already set up):

```
soup.find_all('td', attrs={'bgcolor':'#FFFFCC'})
```

That will find all of your keys. The trick is to associate these with the values you want, which all show up immediately afterward and which are in pairs (if these things change, by the way, this solution won't work).

Thus, you can try the following to access what follows your key entries and put those into your_dictionary:

```
 for node in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'bgcolor':'#FFFFCC'}):
   your_dictionary[node.string] = node.next_sibling
```

The problem is that the "next_sibling" is actually a '\n', so you have to do the following to capture the *next* value (the first value you want):

```
for node in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'bgcolor':'#FFFFCC'}):
  your_dictionary[node.string] = node.next_sibling.next_sibling.string
```

And if you want the *two* following values, you have to double this:

```
for node in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'bgcolor':'#FFFFCC'}):
  your_dictionary[node.string] = [node.next_sibling.next_sibling.string, node.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.next_sibling.string]
```

Disclaimer: that last line is pretty ugly to me.

Comment: This is kind of what I meant about BS's generated model sometimes getting in the way more than helping. The other weak link in BS is that it *must* parse the entire HTML, which makes it fragile in the face of strange HTML. Pyparsing-based scrapers can look just for specific constructs in the HTML (even if *they* are not valid HTML - pyparsing doesn't judge) and skip the rest. Of course, using regex is similar in approach, but re forces you to specify every possible whitespace, upper/lower case, HTML attribute - makeHTMLTags and pyparsing's whitespace skipping take care of all that stuff.

Comment: I agree. That's why I thought your answer was better, even while it is, to be honest, a bit over my head. I was kind of hoping someone would point out something I had overlooked that would obviate the need to do "next_sibling.next_sibling," (which is actually a trick I learned by reading the BeautifulSoup docs). I was thinking of some regex or whitespace tests to make sure we're capturing the stuff requested, but that doesn't get rid of the ugly line. I was also considering some kind of generator object that looks cleaner, but I didn't continue mulling it over.

Comment: Hm, and not only is all this `next_sibling`ing ugly, it is also very whitespace-sensitive - if the `<td>` lines were all on the same line, with no intervening newlines or whitespace, then you would use fewer `next_sibling` calls to iterate through the BS-generated DOM. If you wrote a simple generator named `next_element` that would do the `next_sibling` calls until finding an element node (the next `<td>` node), then you could use `next_element(node).string, next_element(next_element(node)).string` - maybe a little less ugly, but definitely more robust in the face of unpredictable whitespace.

Comment: Ah, I see there is a `node.findNext('td')` call in the BS API, so you could write `(node.findNext('td').string, node.findNext('td').findNext('td').string)` to get a 2-tuple of the next two `td` tags' contents.

Comment: Yes! This is actually useful for some stuff I'm working on. Thanks for helping me think through it

Answer (score 0):

I've used BeautifulSoup 3, but it probably will work under 4.

```
# Import System libraries
import re

# Import Custom libraries
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# This may be different between BeautifulSoup 3 and BeautifulSoup 4
with open("fide.html") as file_h:
    # Read the file into the BeautifulSoup class
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file_h.read())

tr_location = lambda x: x.name == u"tr" # Row location
key_location = lambda x: x.name == u"td" and bool(set([(u"bgcolor", u"#FFFFCC")]) & set(x.attrs)) # Integer key location
td_location = lambda x: x.name == u"td" and not dict(x.attrs).has_key(u"bgcolor") # Float value location

str_key_dict = {}
num_key_dict = {}
for tr in soup.findAll(tr_location): # Loop through all found rows
    for key in tr.findAll(key_location): # Loop through all found Integer key tds
        key_list = []
        key_str = key.text.strip()
        for td in key.findNextSiblings(td_location)[:2]: # Loop through the next 2 neighbouring Float values
            key_list.append(td.text)
        key_list = map(float, key_list) # Convert the text values to floats

        # String based dictionary section
        str_key_dict[key_str] = key_list

        # Number based dictionary section
        num_range = map(int, re.split("\s*-\s*", key_str)) # Extract a value range to perform interpolation
        if(len(num_range) == 2):
            num_key_dict.update([(x, key_list) for x in range(num_range[0], num_range[1] + 1)])
        else:
            num_key_dict.update([(num_range[0], key_list)])

for x in num_key_dict.items():
    print x
```